# Docker dumbell network graph

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I want to try and reproduce (for network simulation purposes) a [network dumbell](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Network-topology-with-standard-dumbbell-bottleneck_fig3_262053709) using Docker and Docker-compose. In order to do this, I declare 3 *internal* networks in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

- `usrnet` (172.20.10.0/24)
- `backbone` (172.20.250.0/24)
- `srvnet` (172.20.20.0/24)

I also declare multiple containers:

- `usr1`, in `usrnet` (172.20.10.101)
- `usr2`, in `usrnet` (172.20.10.102)
- `r1`, in `usrnet` (172.20.10.2) AND `backbone` (172.20.250.2)
- `r2`, in `srvnet` (172.20.20.2) AND `backbone` (172.20.250.3)
- `srv1`, in `srvnet` (172.20.20.101)
- `srv2` in `srvnet` (172.20.20.102)

Then, inside each container, I set the routing rules properly (using `ip route add ...`) so that packets flow directly through containers and not through the host gateway. For instance:

```
root@r1:/# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: eth0@if22: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:14:fa:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.20.250.2/24 brd 172.20.250.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
25: eth1@if26: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:14:0a:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.20.10.2/24 brd 172.20.10.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@r1:/# ip route list
default via 172.20.250.1 dev eth0 
172.20.10.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.10.2 
172.20.20.0/24 via 172.20.250.3 dev eth0 
172.20.250.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.250.2
```

The problem is, when I try to ping for instance `srv1` from `usr1`, the packet source IP keeps getting "masqueraded" as the host gateway addresses:

- `tcpdump` on `usr1` shows IP packets 172.20.10.101 > 172.20.20.101 (as it should be)
- `tcpdump` on `r1` shows IP packets 172.20.10.1 > 172.20.20.101 (masqueraded by `usrnet` gateway ?)
- `tcpdump` on `r2` shows IP packets 172.20.250.1 > 172.20.20.101 (masqueraded by `backbone` gateway ?)
- `tcpdump` on `srv1` shows IP packets 172.20.20.1 > 172.20.20.101 (masqueraded by `srvnet` gateway ?)

So `srv1` answers to 172.20.20.1 (as it is now the source IP of the ICMP echo packet) and the reply is not forwarded back to `usr1`.

I suspect this has to do with docker's `iptables`/`nftables` rules. Indeed, `nft flush ruleset` (on the host), while being a terrible idea, does the trick and my containers can communicate in the intended way.

Is there a "cleaner" way than disabling nft all together ?

Appendix : minimal `docker-compose.yml` setup to reproduce

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  usr1:
    image: weibeld/ubuntu-networking:latest
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    command: sleep 10000
    networks:
      usrnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.10.101
  usr2:
    image: weibeld/ubuntu-networking:latest
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    command: sleep 10000
    networks:
      usrnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.10.102
  r1:
    image: weibeld/ubuntu-networking:latest
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
    command: sleep 10000
    networks:
      usrnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.10.2
      backbone:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.250.2
  r2:
    image: weibeld/ubuntu-networking:latest
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
    command: sleep 10000
    networks:
      srvnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.20.2
      backbone:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.250.3
  srv1:
    image: weibeld/ubuntu-networking:latest
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    command: sleep 10000
    networks:
      srvnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.20.101
  srv2:
    image: weibeld/ubuntu-networking:latest
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    command: sleep 10000
    networks:
      srvnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.20.102

networks:
  backbone:
    internal: true
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.250.0/24
  usrnet:
    internal: true
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.10.0/24
  srvnet:
    internal: true
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.20.0/24
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I managed to make it work on a freshly-installed Debian virtual machine, using exactly this `docker-compose.yml` file, by tuning `iptables` rules.
I flushed the `DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1` chain, put a single `RETURN` rule in it, and then changed the `FORWARD` chain policy to `ACCEPT`.

```
$ sudo nft flush chain ip filter DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
$ sudo nft add rule ip filter DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 return
$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

I could have refined this a bit more, but this was sufficient to let me achieve what I wanted.